# Error 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' ionic2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, ionic2

estoy insertando un iframe en ionic2 importadon desde una url de una pagina he probado unos si me salen y con youtube tambiem pero como el de google o  la preincipal que tengo que colocar http://soporte.estadisticassena.com/edis/www/engenn11le04ob08/ no me deja sale este error:

```
 Refused to display 'http://soporte.estadisticassena.com/edis/www/engenn11le04ob08/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

este es el componente:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AlertController, LoadingController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'sena',
  templateUrl: 'sena.html'
})

export class Sena{

   url: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ){
    this.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.google.com.co/');
  }
}
```

Este es el html:

```
 <iframe class="iframe-sena" height="190" onload="this.width=screen.width" [src]="url" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro de la respuesta de la pagina cargada esta el header HTTP:

x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN

Esto desactiva la visualizacion de esta pagina en un IFRAME. Ver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Desafortunadamente Google y otros sitios han desactivado el soporte para cargar sus contenidos en un iframe de un sitio externo. Revisa https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4542055?hl=en y https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2641279?hl=en

La manera de mostrar este contenido en un iframe ya no es posible de manera normal (usando src en el iframe). La solución mas cercana es usar una pagina "proxy" en tu propio servidor que te sirva el contenido de dicha pagina pero desde un origen local.

Ej: Cargar una pagina local

```
<iframe src="mysite/proxypage?url=http://www.google.com/search?q=test"></iframe>
```

Y el controlador de la pagina descarga el contenido de la url y lo entrega como respuesta.

Comment: Hola @Igor, algun sitio donde encontrar un ejemplo de como hacer el proxy web? Tambien existiria la opcion de permitir en el server XFRAME: ALLOW FROM: url de la app. ¿Cual seria la url origen de una app ionic?